# How to insert element in dictionary with duplicate key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary:

```
{2:1, 5:4, 6:9}
```

And if I trying to insert another element which has same key which present in existing dictionary like {2:3}.

So is that any way to insert the element in dictionary which has same key in python. Or it will give error.

Comment: It will give you an error. What are you trying to achieve that requires duplicate keys?

Comment: Keys in dictionaries have to be unique. There can't be a duplicate key. But you can make the values to be lists.

Comment: Consider list of tuples od a `pandas` Series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only thing you can do is add another value to that key and make the values a list:

```
d = {2:1, 5:4, 6:9}

d.update({2:[d[2],3]})
```

output:

```
{2: [1, 3], 5: 4, 6: 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary works like sets (duplicates are not allowed) However, there is some work around by storing multiple values for a key in a list.

```
my_dictionary = {2: [1, 3], 5: [4, 7, 6], 3: [0]}
```

And if you run

```
{3: 5, 2: 3}.update({2: 1})
```

it won't give an error, it will just update the value for the given key (2)

Output:

```
{3: 5, 2: 1}
```